# Insert new records from different table on condition

Tags: postgresql, join, insert

I am trying to add new records to table_1 from table_2 via JOIN but I am not getting the correct result.

I am trying to copy latitude and longitude from table_2 to table_1.
I have table_1 with columns address, latitude, longitude
where latitude & longitude is blank.

table_2 has columns address, latitude, longitude, name, address, etc.
In both tables address has just a city name.

```
insert into table_1 (latitude, longitude)
select  table_2.latitude, table_2.longitude from table_2 JOIN table_1 ON  table_1.address = table_2.address;
```

```
Getting this output: table_1

address  latitude longitude
city_1    NULL     NULL
city_2    NULL     NULL
city_3    NULL     NULL
NULL     123.12    123.12
NULL     123.12    123.12
NULL     123.12    123.12
```

Where I am expecting something like this:

```
address  latitude longitude
city_1    123.12    123.12 
city_2    123.12    123.12
city_3    123.12    123.12
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use the `update` statement instead of `insert`, since the entries in the first table one already exist, and you just need to update them

```
update table_1  set latitude = mapped_t2.latitude, longitude = mapped_t2.longitude
  from (select table_2.address, table_2.latitude, table_2.longitude from table_2 join table_1 on table_1.address = table_2.address) as mapped_t2
     where mapped_t2.address = table_1.address
```

Demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=00d7f63628642e00bcaa8a2bff0512cd)